# Метод фильтрует массив, оставляя только четные числа

Tags: java, массивы, if, for, return

По заданию нужно написать метод для возвращения массива только с четными числами.
осталось последнее задание. Никак не пойму как мне вернуть этот самый массив. return происходит после цикла for, а что записать в if? всю голову сломал, интернет перекопал.пробовал новый массив создать с нужными числами,но тоже не получается. не понимаю как добавить в новый массив четные числа.

```
@Override
public int[] getEvenDigits(int[] values) {
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
        if ( values[i] % 2 == 0) {

        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

Comment: чисто этот же массив не выйдет вернуть. Надо новый создавать

Comment: как в новый массив отправить данные?

Comment: `int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(oldArray, startIndex, endIndex);`, где индексы - индекс числа четного. Но это немного неэффективно. Потому что мы каждый раз пересоздаем массив.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import  java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        
        int[] even = getEvenDigits(arr);
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(even));
    }
    
    public static int[] getEvenDigits(int[] values) {
        int j = 0;
        int[] even = new int[values.length];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i] % 2 == 0) {
                even[j] = values[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        return Arrays.copyOf(even, j);
    }
}
```

Comment: хвала тебе, добрый друг!

Answer (score 1):

в if-е добавляй получившиеся элементы в отдельный массив с только четными числами